# Change path in the Data Environment

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have to write apps that draw their data from the company's main app. It does not use a database, only tables, and everything (exe, dbfs, frx) is in the same directory.
I created a test directory that is a copy of the live directory. Now, if I use the data environment of my forms rather than load/unload, the path indicated in the properties of each table points, of course, to my test directory. 
Is there a way to change that path dynamically when I transfer the exe to the live directory?

Comment: Setup a datapath table with the fields 'App', 'Test', and 'Production'. Add the folder paths to the test and production fields for your app. Then in your program, look for that table and add the folder path you need to a variable. Then you can do `USE gVariable + 'tablename.dbf' in 0`.

Comment: In search path or not, as long as the path recorded in DE exists, it is used. You have to change the path of DE objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using DataEnvironments, then VFP holds the **exact** path (not relative) to the database and\or tables. Then:

If that path exists exactly on the machine where exe is used then VFP uses the tables from that path. 
If that path doesn't exist then it uses the 'search path'.

To overcome this situation, I wrote a small routine called UpdateDE.prg many years ago and I simply have:

```
UpdateDE(this)
```

in forms' DE BeforeOpenTables method. This works very nicely, you keep your development path, and still you can test customer's data if you wanted to just by changing the 'path' in a little dbf. Here is the UpdateDE.prg code:

```
Lparameters toDE
Do setups && prg keeping common "set" entries
Local Array aDEMembers[1]
Local lnMembers,ix,lcMembers
If !(Type('oApp')='O' And !Isnull(m.oApp))
  Public oApp
  oApp = Createobject('myApp')
Endif
lnMembers = Amembers(aDEMembers,m.toDE,2)
For ix=1 To m.lnMembers
  With Evaluate('toDe.'+aDEMembers[m.ix])
    If Lower(.BaseClass) == 'cursor'
      If Atc(oApp.cAppDBC,.Database) > 0
        .Database = Addbs(oApp.cAppDataPath)+oApp.cAppDBC
      Else
        .CursorSource = Addbs(oApp.cAppDataPath)+Justfname(.CursorSource)
      Endif
    Endif
  Endwith
Endfor

Define Class myApp As Custom
  cAppDBC = 'myDatabase.dbc'
  cAppDataPath=Fullpath('data')
  cCurPath = ''
  Procedure Init
    This.cCurPath = Set('path')
    If File('dbparam.dbf') && a small dbf that holds path to current data folder
      Select dataLoc From dbparam Where locType == 'DATABASE' Into Array arrDataLoc
      If _Tally > 0
        This.cAppDataPath = arrDataLoc
        Set Path To (arrDataLoc[1]+';'+This.cCurPath)
      Endif
      Use In 'dbparam'
    Endif
  Endproc
  Procedure Destroy
    Set Path To (This.cCurPath)
  Endproc
Enddefine
```

Answer (score 1):

If the forms and the tables are in the same folder or in the same folder relative to each other in the development and runtime environments, all should work as you expect.

Specifically, the DE contains a relative path to the tables you add (even though it looks like it's absolute). If you open the form as a table (USE MyForm.SCX) and take a look, you'll see relative paths.

If you need to work with the test data in a different relative position than the data will be at runtime, check this article: http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~HowToChangePathInDataEnvironment~WIN_COM_API

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Fox has the habit of storing relative or absolute paths in the data environments of forms, reports and so on. This is can be convenient if the design environment is identical to the user environment (i.e. almost never) but mostly it is a nuisance and a source of subtle bugs.

Fox ignores the stored path if a cursor with the right name is already open; hence you can make Fox use whatever you want - regardless of the stored paths - if you open your tables manually or create suitable cursors. If you remove the stored path components by hacking the .frx/.scx memos with a simple script (which I always do) then you can eliminate a whole class of Heisenbugs.

In general I open all tables with explicit paths provided by a context object (environment manager) or relative to a DBC; there's never any data in the PATH except in interactive Foxen (IDE). Our work is interesting enough as it is and I don't need any interference from PATH-related bugs...